# How to my app says how many times the user enter a value before make the right choice?

Tags: command-line

I'm new in Obj-C, I created a command-line app, the objective of my app is very simple, the system choose a random number and the user have to say this number, trying, for example: If the number is 30 and the user put 28, the system says is too low, if is 32, says is too high. When the user get the right choice, the system have to say: You played .. times before get the right choice! But how I configure this? Sorry for the simple question, well, not so simple for me.

Answer (score 1):

What he is saying declare a variable like:

```
int count = 0;
```

then in the while loop use `count++;` this will count the number of times they guess
in the

```
NSLog(@"you have guessed %d guess's", count);
```

I am new to Objective c too but this worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple programming. Keep an integer around, say Count, and initialize it to 0. Everytime the guess is wrong, increase it by 1. When the guess is correct, just output that integer together with "You played... ". I don't know much about objective C so I can only provide you with a sample C code (it is usable in Obj-C though):

```
void runNumberGame(int num) //num here is your hidden number
{
    int Cnt = 0; //this is the variable that you use to keep track of how many times you have tried
    int ans; //this variable is used to store the answer

    while (true)
    {
        scanf(ans);
        Cnt++;
        if (ans == num){
            printf("You played %d times.\n", Cnt);
            break;
        }
        else if (ans > num)
            printf("Too high\n");
        else
            printf("Too low\n");
    }
}
```

Call this function with the hidden number you want to use, for example:

```
runNumberGame(30);
```

Comment: Hey Zekareisoujin,

Well.. I'm very new in programming, I never used xcode before, Obj-C it's the language that I try to start all this thing of programming, could u be explain this a little more detailed?